# how we get Uncheckitems CheckBoxList control in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

when user uncheckitems items.how we get that uncheckitems

```
for (int i = 0; i < ChkLstUserRoles.Items.Count; i++)
{
     if (ChkLstUserRoles.Items[i].Selected == true)
     {
         URoles = URoles + "|" + ChkLstUserRoles.Items[i].Value;
         ActivityLog = ActivityLog + "Grant the " + ChkLstUserRoles.Items[i].Text + " to  user [" + CboUserName.Text + "]çGrantRole|";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition,

```
ChkLstUserRoles.Items[i].Selected == false
```